# Best practice for a progress bar while waiting on a modal to display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have an online application whose functionality includes right clicking on a value and returning in a small, floating modal box some PHP/MySQL retrieved information. The Javascript function looks like this;

```
function getCallHistory() {
    $('tr').on('contextmenu', 'td', function(e) { //Get td under tr and invoke on contextmenu

        e.preventDefault(); //Prevent defaults'
            var idparm = $(this).attr('id');
            var arparm = idparm.split(":");
            var id     = arparm[1];
                id     = id.replace(/\s+/g, '');
            var call   = $(this).html();
            var call   = call.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // remove spaces
                    //Look for slash or dash (/,-, or any special character)
                    var vals = [call].map((item) => item.split(/\W+/,1));
                    var call = vals[0];

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getCallHistory.php",  
            data: {call : call, id : id},
            success: function(response) {

                $("#lli").html(response);  // Writes to the lli DIV at the bottom of index.php

                $("#lli").modal();  // Opens the modal dialog box
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Last Query Failed, try again.');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Sometimes the MySql takes a few seconds to return and build the modal using PHP. During that short time I would like to display some kind of indicator that its working. The time is short a few seconds at most so I'm not looking for a progress bar so much as a spinning beachball or equivalent.

Is there a better way than others to accomplish this? An example someplace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this works in your context but I think you should just show the modal right away with a "Please wait" message so this is how the code *could* look:

```
function getCallHistory() {
    $('tr').on('contextmenu', 'td', function(e) { //Get td under tr and invoke on contextmenu

        // Show the modal right away with a message
        $("#lli").html('Loading fresh call history, please wait...');
        $("#lli").modal();

        e.preventDefault(); //Prevent defaults'
            var idparm = $(this).attr('id');
            var arparm = idparm.split(":");
            var id     = arparm[1];
                id     = id.replace(/\s+/g, '');
            var call   = $(this).html();
            var call   = call.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // remove spaces
                    //Look for slash or dash (/,-, or any special character)
                    var vals = [call].map((item) => item.split(/\W+/,1));
                    var call = vals[0];

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getCallHistory.php",  
            data: {call : call, id : id},
            success: function(response) {

                // Overwrite the waiting message
                $("#lli").html(response);  // Writes to the lli DIV at the bottom of index.php

                $("#lli").modal();  // Opens the modal dialog box
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Last Query Failed, try again.');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot. Its simple and does exactly what I now know I wanted. LOL